# Azure ARM templates deployment Github integration (with deploy keys)

Tags: azure, github, azure-web-app-service

I want to do ARM templates deployment for web app which has source code on Github. So far after quite some trial and error, I am able to use following format:

`"apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "web",
    "type": "sourcecontrols",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "RepoUrl": "https://github.com/user/repo.git", 
        "branch": "dev",
        "IsManualIntegration": true
    }
}`

This is manual integration. It seems to work if I have previously used Github and authorised Azure. Isn't there any way to automatically setup and sync Github repo? Is there any way to use deploy keys?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but not with ARM Template. Follow the steps [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment).

But if you've setup Github **once** on your subscription you can use this manual integration for all deployments in this subscription and it will work, so nothing to worry about.